# Remove weighty content from .gradle directory

Tags: gradle

After just starting using Gradle I found the following problem.

**Background:** There is a simple project with Kotlin DSL, Kotlin as the application programming language and Spring Boot (this is just to make it more specific, the same problem exists in the other setups).

**The problem:** After the project is built, in the project's directory I see the `.gradle` directory that weights about 100M.

**Why is this a problem?** Of cause I can ignore this directory in my Git repo, but the directory where I keep my project is subject to backing up, and I don't want to backup these generated "garbage" content.

**The question:** How to move the `.gradle` directory outside of my project's directory, let's say somewhere into a temporary directory? Or how to move the most weighty content (like the cache) outside the project's directory?

I found some solutions in the Gradle docs but they require usage of some command line arguments. I'd prefer defining this configuration in the Gradle specific files (like `build.gradle.kts` or `settings.gradle.kts`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting cannot go in `settings.gradle.kts` or `build.gradle.kts` because Gradle needs to know what it is before compiling those files.

Instead you can set it in a `gradle.properties` file (see [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)). You can create such a file in your project's root directory and write the following on ones of the lines to move your Gradle cache to a different directory:

```
org.gradle.projectcachedir=[directory]
```

If it's a relative path it's relative to the project directory, or you can use an absolute path.

Comment: Looks like working and I'll try to use it. But I also want to use environment variables in the property values definition like this `org.gradle.projectcachedir=${TEMP}/gradle_cache`. It doesn't work in my case and I can find nothing in the documentation. Is it really possible?

Comment: For that I think you'd need to write a shell script and then pass the appropriate value to Gradle as a command line argument.